# OpenAI API error: "NameError: name 'client' is not defined"

Tags: python, telegram, openai-api, gpt-3

This is my code:

```py
import telebot
import openai
 
bot = telebot.TeleBot("0")
openai.api_key = "0"
 
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    print(message.chat.title, message.chat.username)
    if message.chat.id == -1002097745017:
    #print(message.text)
        if "@0" in message.text:
            message.text = (message.text).replace("@0 ", "")
            #print(message.text)
            response = client.completions.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613", prompt=message.text, max_tokens=1000)
            full_response = response['choices'][0]['text']  # Use the text property of the first element of the choices list to access the full response
            lines = full_response.splitlines()  # Split the response into individual lines
            for line in lines:  # Iterate over the lines
                try:
                    #print(line)
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, line)  # Send each line back to the user as a separate message
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "work only - tg.com/123123")
 
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

I'm getting the following error:

> NameError: name 'client' is not defined

If I change this...

```
response = client.completions.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613", prompt=message.text, max_tokens=1000)
```

...to this.

```
response = openai.Completion.create(model="text-davinci-003", prompt=message.text, max_tokens=1000)
```

Then I'm getting the following error:

> This is a chat model and not supported in the v1/completions endpoint. Did you mean to use v1/chat/completions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried multiple combinations, but not the right one.

- Use `openai` not `client`, because you didn't initialize OpenAI with `client`, but with `openai`.
- Use `completions.create` method name, not `Completion.create` if you're using OpenAI Python SDK version `>=1.0.0`.
- Use the [Completions](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/completions-api) model, not the [Chat Completions](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/chat-completions-api) model. While the `text-davinci-003` *is* a Completions model, it will not work because it was deprecated not long ago. Use `gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct` instead, which is the recommended replacement for the `text-davinci-003`.

The following should work:

```
response = openai.completions.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct", prompt=message.text, max_tokens=1000)
```

Comment: yep, its right but first answer from bot:

Form() {
return "developers/helloForm";
}
@RequestMapping("hello")
public ModelAndView hello(String gallinit,String gallfee,ModelAndView mav) {
int gallinit1=Integer.parseInt(gallinit);
int gallfee1=Integer.parseInt(gallfee);
t=2500*((gallinit1/2)+gallinit1+gallinit1+gallinit1+(((double)gallinit1)/2));
f=59000+55000+23000+19000+gallfee1;
System.out.println(t+"원");
System.out.println(t-f+"원");
mav.setViewName("developers/helloworld");
mav.addObject("total", t);
mav.addObject("earning", t-f);

Comment: @sdfsdfsdfsdf See my updated answer. Let me know if this solves your problem.